# Create Mime PCAP File

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I need to generate a pcap file containing a specifically crafted mime message I have already built. Are there any programs capable of generating such files or is my only option to use tcpdump/wireshark to edit an existing smtp/mime exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark, tcpdump, and friends are designed for analyzing traces, not generating them. Thus you will find very limited editing support in these tools. In order to manipulate packet traces, have a look at [Netdude](http://netdude.sourceforge.net). If a GUI does not suite your needs, you may also use [libnetdude](http://netdude.sourceforge.net/plugins-libnetdude.html) to work on the trace programmatically.

However, it would probably still be easier if you sent your MIME message to a machine under your control and capture the traffic with tcpdump.

Comment: At this point in time I think building my own VM for capturing traffic may be my best option. I have been looking at this problem every way I can and unless I sit down and spend the next 2 weeks writing a program used to generate finite traffic, I'm SOL.